Getting Error "Invalid Url" Bad Request when executing "runCommand@2024-07-01" in bicep template via VSCode
I am trying to deploy a bicep file on Azure so that it creates a VM with Windows OS, Install IIS, Downloads code from a Public GitHub Repo, Reboot the machine. I am able to complete all the steps via DSC extension except the last one. Last step is required else the website won't show up the downloaded code. For last step I have used runcommand, but I keep getting Invalid Url, (Bad Request).
As a troubleshooting step I even changed the reboot command to echo command, but I keep getting same error.
In order to create this script I took inspiration from https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale and tweaked it for a VM.
Here is the code:
@description('Name of the virtual machine.')
param vmName string = 'vm1'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
@description('Size of the virtual machine.')
param vmSize string = 'Standard_D2s_v3'
param adminUsername string = 'adminUser'
param adminPassword string = 'some-secret-password'
param vNetName string ='vnet1'
param subnetName string='subnet1'
param nsgName string='nsg1'
var nicName = '${vmName}-nic'
resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2024-03-01' existing = {
  name: nsgName
}

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2022-05-01' = {
  name: nicName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipconfig1'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
          subnet: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vNetName, subnetName)
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    networkSecurityGroup:{
      id: nsg.id
    }
  }
}

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2022-03-01' = {
  name: vmName
  location: location
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: vmSize
    }
    osProfile: {
      computerName: vmName
      adminUsername: adminUsername
      adminPassword: adminPassword
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
        offer: 'WindowsServer'
        sku: '2019-Datacenter'
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: 'Standard_LRS'
        }
      }
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: nic.id
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource vmExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: vm
  name: 'IIS'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Powershell'
    type: 'DSC'
    typeHandlerVersion: '2.9'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      configuration: {
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/refs/heads/master/demos/vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/DSC/InstallIIS.zip'
        script: 'InstallIIS.ps1'
        function: 'InstallIIS'
      }
      configurationArguments: {
        nodeName: 'localhost'
        WebDeployPackagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/refs/heads/master/demos/vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/WebDeploy/DefaultASPWebApp.v1.0.zip'
      }
    }
  }
}

resource rebootCommand 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand@2024-07-01' = {
  parent: vm
  name: 'reboot'
  location: location
  properties: {
    asyncExecution: false
    source: {
      script: 'echo Hello World'
    }
  }
}


Do you have the exact error message please?Also does the runCommand script supposed to be running after the vmExtension ?

yes, it is suppose to run after vmExtension. This is the exact message "Invalid Url (Bad Request" for runCommand

{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "The request URL is not valid."
}

you prob need an explicit dependsOn to make sure it run after vmExtension. If the vm extension script is doing a reboot that may cause the vm to be unvailable


"Invalid Url" Bad Request when executing "runCommand@2024-07-01" in bicep template via VSCode

Thanks thomas for pointing right insight for the issue by mentioning the use of depends_on.
Here the action to run the module depends on the status of the vm extension installation. The provision of the runcommand should be done after deploying the extension. I extensively use the modular approach for the smoother operation as per the sequence of the deployment.
Demo configuration:
main.bicep:
@description('Name of the virtual machine.')
param vmName string = 'vm1'

@description('Azure region for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Size of the virtual machine.')
param vmSize string = 'Standard_D2s_v3'

@description('Admin username for the virtual machine.')
param adminUsername string = 'adminUser'

@secure()
@description('Admin password for the virtual machine.')
param adminPassword string

@description('Name of the virtual network.')
param vNetName string = 'vnet1'

@description('Name of the subnet.')
param subnetName string = 'subnet1'

@description('Name of the network security group.')
param nsgName string = 'nsg1'

module networkModule 'modules/network.bicep' = {
  name: 'networkDeployment'
  params: {
    location: location
    vNetName: vNetName
    subnetName: subnetName
    nsgName: nsgName
    vmName: vmName
  }
}

module vmModule 'modules/vm.bicep' = {
  name: 'vmDeployment'
  params: {
    location: location
    vmName: vmName
    vmSize: vmSize
    adminUsername: adminUsername
    adminPassword: adminPassword
    nicId: networkModule.outputs.nicId
  }
}

module iisModule 'modules/iis.bicep' = {
  name: 'iisDeployment'
  params: {
    location: location
    vmName: vmName
  }
  dependsOn: [
    vmModule
  ]
}

output vmName string = vmModule.outputs.vmName
output nicId string = networkModule.outputs.nicId
output vnetName string = networkModule.outputs.vnetName
output nsgName string = networkModule.outputs.nsgName

module/iis.bicep:
// modules/iis.bicep
param location string
param vmName string

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2023-03-01' existing = {
  name: vmName
}

resource iisExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-03-01' = {
  parent: vm
  name: 'IIS'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Powershell'
    type: 'DSC'
    typeHandlerVersion: '2.9'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      configuration: {
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/demos/vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/DSC/InstallIIS.zip'
        script: 'InstallIIS.ps1'
        function: 'InstallIIS'
      }
      configurationArguments: {
        nodeName: 'localhost'
        WebDeployPackagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/demos/vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/WebDeploy/DefaultASPWebApp.v1.0.zip'
      }
    }
  }
}

resource rebootCommand 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands@2023-03-01' = {
  parent: vm
  name: 'reboot'
  location: location
  properties: {
    asyncExecution: false
    source: {
      script: 'Write-Host "Rebooting the machine"; Restart-Computer -Force'
    }
    timeoutInSeconds: 1800
  }
  dependsOn: [
    iisExtension
  ]
}

Configuration:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2022-11-01/virtualmachines/runcommands?pivots=deployment-language-bicep
Bicep warnings and error codes - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
